# Finding the median in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I want to find the median of some grouping by the following query:

```
g.V().
  groupCount().
    by('someProp').
  order(local).
    by(values, asc).
  sideEffect(unfold().
    count().as('size').
    math('size/2').store('middle')).
    unfold().
    select(values).
  skip(select('middle')).limit(1)
```

But I'm having a hard time using the "middle" variable in the skip.
What is the "gremlin" way to accomplish such a query?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'm not sure I have ever quite considered this use case before. My initial thinking is that perhaps some combination of `index` and `group` can be used to create a group that can be selected by number. However, the `math` step will yield double precision results which is a complication so `sack may be an alternative. I'm going to ponder this one a bit.

Comment: After a bit of thought, I added an answer below that I hope gives you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this test graph

```java
g.addV('Person').property(id,'p1').property('age',28).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p2').property('age',36).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p3').property('age',22).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p4').property('age',55).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p5').property('age',22).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p6').property('age',28).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p7').property('age',28).
  addV('Person').property(id,'p8').property('age',63)
```

The `groupCount` yields

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   groupCount().
......2>     by('age').
......3>   order(local).
......4>     by(values, asc)

==>[36:1,55:1,63:1,22:2,28:3]
```

From there we can use a similar calculation as in the original question but using `sack` as the calculations will yield integer results.

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   groupCount().
......2>     by('age').
......3>   order(local).
......4>     by(values, asc).
......5>   sack(assign).by(count(local)).
......6>   sack(div).by(constant(2)).sack()

==>2
```

From there we can index the sorted map

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   groupCount().
......2>     by('age').
......3>   order(local).
......4>     by(values, asc).
......5>   sack(assign).by(count(local)).
......6>   sack(div).by(constant(2)).
......7>   index().
......8>   unfold().as('a')
==>[36=1,0]
==>[55=1,1]
==>[63=1,2]
==>[22=2,3]
==>[28=3,4]
```

All that remains is to select just the item that matches our computed `sack` value.

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   groupCount().
......2>     by('age').
......3>   order(local).
......4>     by(values, asc).
......5>   sack(assign).by(count(local)).
......6>   sack(div).by(constant(2)).
......7>   index().
......8>   unfold().as('a').
......9>   where(eq('a')).
.....10>     by(sack()).
.....11>     by(tail(local))  

==>[63=1,2]
```

We could also go one step further, and remove the index from the final result.

```java
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   groupCount().
......2>     by('age').
......3>   order(local).
......4>     by(values, asc).
......5>   sack(assign).by(count(local)).
......6>   sack(div).by(constant(2)).
......7>   index().
......8>   unfold().as('a').
......9>   where(eq('a')).
.....10>     by(sack()).
.....11>     by(tail(local)).
.....12> limit(local,1)

==>63=1
```

Comment: Thanks! @Kelvin Lawrence